# Developing WFP with Dev C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, wfp

I want to run [this example WFP application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29026/Firewall-using-Vista-s-Windows-Filtering-Platform), but when I try to compile it with Dev C++ (5.5.3), the compiler says that

```
::FwpmEngineOpen0 has not been declared
```

The same for all of the WFP API functions and strctures. I suspect that I need to include something in the header or/and add some compiler parameters, but I don't know where to find any info about it.

Comment: @BrianGradin WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) is not the same as WFP (Windows Filtering Platform)

Comment: I can't be certain but I think Dev C++ is out of date, i.e., not maintained, or so I've read somewhere, for a long time. I've seen projects that are supposedly keeping it going but perhaps read [Why You Shouldn't Use Dev C++](http://clicktobegin.net/programming/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/).

Answer (score 0):

You need the Windows Desktop SDK 2008 or later installed to develop for WFP. I'm not familiar with your compiler so I don't know what SDK versions it's compatible with, but the latest version is on Microsoft's [Downloads for developing desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904949) page.